# How can more than one input trigger an operation in Pure Data?

Tags: puredata

I need an operation to be performed whenever a change in a control is performed. Operations are only performed when the left input is changed or it receives a bang.

Right now I'm achieving this by using a `[t b f]` object, like this:

[image: trigger two inputs]

This works for two inputs (I still wonder if there is a different, better, less ugly approach though) but things get uglier and uglier as more inputs are needed.

For three inputs, for example, I thought about something like this:

[image: trigger 3 inputs]

But I don't know, I feel that there are better alternatives (maybe there's a bug with this?)

What is the common way to implement multiple controls triggering an operation? Which are my options here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the answers in the mailing list, it seems that using a `[t b f]` object is how this is handled. When more than one input is involved, each input needs its own `[t b f]`object:

[image: multiple t b f]